# How can I use Webpack in an Ionic Version 1 app? (Is it possible/are there alternatives?)

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, webpack

I've never used Webpack in an ionic project and I am trying to use it like I would  in `node.js` project and I'm getting the error 
`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require` so I seems as though I wouldn't use webpack the same way. How can I do this in my Ionic version 1 project?

So far I add the bundle in my `index.html`

`<script src="app/main/myapp.bundle.js"></script>`

and inside I import all my other `scripts` like so

`require('../common/myimport')`

removing the

`<script src="app/common/myimport.js"></script>`

in my `index.html`

Then if I run

`webpack ./www/app/main/app.js ./www/app/main/myapp.bundle.js`

I get that error.

So can I use `webpack` in ionic, and if so how can I import my scripts into the `bundle`?

Comment: The short answer: Yes. The long answer: I haven't tried it, but I haven't found any reason why this can't work. You must provide access to your code to check what is happening in your case, but the fact to fails to find the "require" function seems to say that you're not providing the right webpack bundle. So, as I said befor, please show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. It is the same as for any angular 1.x application.

I have made project template for this purpose with all required configuration files for webpack:

https://github.com/zxbodya/angular-webpack-seed